# Precision and recall for SVM from Confusion matrix is different from Precision-Recall graph

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, auc, precision-recall

Coming from Stackoverflow-

So, I am creating a SVM model for a highly imbalanced data set and trying to create to calculate F, Pression and recall from the confusion matrix of the model. Confusion matrix is shown below and graph generated for this model is also attached. My question is, the calculated F, Precision and recall from the Confusion Matrix is very high (more than 97%) but the graph says less.

Why is that ? Any inputs, am I missing something here.

```
 Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 1104    2
         1    0    6
```

[image]